# Set focus to next input field in a table after maxlength reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, autofocus

How to set focus to next input field in a table?

Firstly I worked with that JQuery code: But it only works if the input fields are not spread over different  and  fields. How could I improve it that code or maybe someone knows a JS code that will work for autofocus fields spread over td and tr fields following tabindex?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        if(this.value.length==$(this).attr("maxlength")){
            $(this).next().focus();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My html:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="field1"  tabindex="1" name="test1" maxlength = "1"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="field2"  tabindex="2" name="test2"  maxlength = "1">.</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" id="field3"  tabindex="3" name="test3"  maxlength = "1"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a JSFiddle so that people can test your code and provide solutions quickly by copying your JSFiddle into their answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can retrieve all `input` elements and get the `index` of the current one within that collection. To move to the next input, select it from the collection using `eq()` and the next incremental index value.

Also note that your HTML is invalid - you seem to be missing a `<tr>` around the final `td`. I've corrected that in the following example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $inputs = $('input').on('input', e => {
    let $input = $(e.target);
    let index = $inputs.index($input);
    if ($input.val().length === $input.prop('maxlength')) {
      $inputs.eq(index + 1).focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="field1" tabindex="1" name="test1" maxlength="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="field2" tabindex="2" name="test2" maxlength="1">.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="field3" tabindex="3" name="test3" maxlength="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect! I added the tr td - just wrote it to show an example for what I wish. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty gross, but would work lol

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table input').keyup(function(){
        if(this.value.length==$(this).attr("maxlength")){
            tableInputs = $('table').find('input');
            $(tableInputs[tableInputs.index(this)+1]).focus();
        }
    });
});
```